# Is it safe to check a uint mapping's value >0 in a require?

Tags: solidity, security, mapping, require, access

**Context:**

A common access check or modifier is to use something like:
`require(boolMapping[msg.sender] == true);` to ensure the caller is approved to use a function.

Since `mapping (address => uint256) uintMapping` defaults all unset values to `0`, my question is:

**Question:**
Is it safe to use this:

`require(uintMapping[msg.sender] > 0, "not authorised");`

instead of this:

`require(boolMapping[msg.sender] == true, "not authorised");`

to restrict use of a function, assuming pre-authorised accounts are set with values greater than zero?

(This would help condense the amount of storage required on a contract where users already have associated non-zero numbers, as we wouldn't need to use a struct or a second auth mapping).

**Thank you!**

Comment: Why? If zero isn't a valid value then it should be fine, but you have to enforce when saving to the mapping that zero isn't stored.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael . Good point about enforcing non-zero values for members in the mapping. The reason is to save a bit of gas and increase efficiency with my storage structures (previously I had a uintMapping _and_ a boolMapping, but the boolMapping was only ever used to check authorisation before using the uintMapping).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there shouldn't be any issue with this approach.